# ¿Tipo de dato para guardar direcciones ip en mysql?

Tags: mysql, ip

Pues eso, cual es la mejor manera o la más recomendable para guardar direcciónes ip en mysql, tanto direcciones ipv4 como ipv6

Aclarando, lo que quiero saber es en que tipo de dato guardar una direccion ip, lo podria guardar de tipo varchar considerandolo como una cadena, entonces me genera una duda si es la mejor manera o si existen mejores maneras o mas recomendables que funcionen con ipv4 e ipv6

Comment: Lo que quieres es generar una tabla con direcciones IP? o hablas de algo parecido a LinkServer?

Comment: Hola revisa [ask] para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida y realiza el [tour]!

Answer (score 5):

Creo que tu pregunta debio ser esta por lo que te entiendo.
**con que tipo de dato guardo las direcciones IP en mysql**

Cuando necesitamos guardar direcciones IP en nuestras bases de datos, lo más cómodo (y que casi hacemos por inercia) es asignar al campo un tipo VARCHAR con una longitud de 15 caracteres. Sin embargo, existe una opción mejor que poco a poco voy encontrándome en los principales CMS y Frameworks: INT UNSIGNED.

Así, utilizando el comando de MySQL INET_ATON, la dirección IP quedaría codificada en una cadena de 4 bytes que podríamos recuperar mediante su contrario INET_NTOA

```
# Tomamos una direccion IP y la convertimos en una cadena de enteros:
SELECT INET_ATON('192.168.0.10') AS ipn;
# Esto se traduciría en 3232235530

# El proceso inverso:
SELECT INET_NTOA(3232235530) AS ipa;
# Nos devuelve nuestra direccion IP anterior: 192.168.0.10
```

Comment: esta respuesta como la otra es buena.. salvo que quieras hacer una tabla de lockup, lo que ganas de espacio lo "perderias" en velocidad para hacer busquedas...

Answer (score 2):

MySql asi como menciona la respuesta anterior utiliza la función INET_ATON() para convertir una dirección ip en un valor entero, y la función INET_NTOA() para hacer lo contrario, a partir de un valor númerico lo convierte en una dirección ip. El inconveniente es que solo soporta direcciones ip en su versión 4.

Mientras que para guardar direcciones ip en su versión 6 se puede ocupar la función **INET6_ATON()** la cual nos retorna un valor de tipo **VARBINARY**: VARBINARY(16) para ipv6 y VARBINARY(4) para ipv4.

```
SELECT HEX(INET6_ATON('10.0.5.9'));
->'0A000509'

#Realizando un proceso contrario
SELECT INET6_NTOA(UNHEX('0A000509'));
->'10.0.5.9'
```

Y para direcciones ipv6

```
SELECT HEX(INET6_ATON(fdfe::5a55:caff:fefa:9089));
->'FDFE0000000000005A55CAFFFEFA9089'

# y el proceso inverso
SELECT INET6_NTOA(UNHEX('FDFE0000000000005A55CAFFFEFA9089'));
->'fdfe::5a55:caff:fefa:9089'
```